# Demonstrations with Venn Diagrams

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Show, using the Venn Diagram, that:

1. $A \subset B \iff A \cup B = B$
2. $A \subset B \iff A \cap B = A$

How to demonstrate something like this using Venn diagrams?

Answer (score 0):

Draw your circles you form 3 regions, $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$ and $B\setminus A$. Prove that $A\subset B$, $A\cup B=B$ and $A\cap B=A$ are equivalent to the region $A\setminus B$ to be empty (or inexistent).

Comment: $\Huge\bigcirc\hspace{-20px}\Huge\bigcirc$ in otherwords. fill is a bit annoying.